# Problem - The FastCGI pool queue is full

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am encountering a problem where the following error is reported:

> `The FastCGI pool queue is full`

Why would this be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try increasing the FastCGI "Queue Length" for your PHP CGI application.

Launch IIS Manager and open the FastCGI settings feature by double clicking on it:

[image]

Select your PHP CGI application (the path may be slightly different from the one shown below), click Edit on the RHS pane. This will open a dialogue where you can change the queue length:

[image]

The FastCGI queue length as described in the docs:

*Specifies the maximum number of requests that can be queued for a FastCGI process pool. Acceptable values are in the range from 1 through 10000000.
The default value is 1000.*

Comment: Apart from raising the queue length, Increasing the number of instances can also help.